# SQL: Getting implicit ratings as a user-item list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables

- a user table `user` with an `id` field
- an items table `item`, also with an id field
- a table `positiverating` with the fields `customerid` and `itemid` which has an entry if the user gave an implicit positive rating for an item (e.g. has seen/bought/clicked/... it)

I want to select the fields `user.id`, `item.id` and `rating` (boolean field)such that for every user and every item `rating` is `true` iif there exists an entry in the `positiverating` table and otherwise `false`?

Some thoughts:

- `SELECT user.id, item.id from user, item` results in the cross
  product needed.
- `positiveratings` more or less is such a cross product, but only for rated items

Assuming that there are 100000 items and the same amount of users, the resulting query needs to be quite efficiently. I suspect some left/right joins are needed, but I feel a bit stuck.

To be more specific, I need a query for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select u.userid, i.itemid, (pr.itemid is not null)
from user u cross join
     item i left outer join
     positiverating pr
     on pr.userid = u.userid and pr.itemid = i.itemid;
```

This assumes no duplicate user/item combinations in the `positiverating` table.

If you have duplicates in `positiverating`, you could use a `group by`.  However, I would recommend using `exists` instead.  I think the following will work:

```
select u.userid, i.itemid,
       exists (select 1 from postivierating where pr.userid = u.userid and pr.itemid = i.itemid)
from user u cross join
     item i;
```

Comment: Looks great. What if there were duplicates in positiverating? A user could visit/buy an item more than once. Maybe count that?